# middleware not access within multiple Route::group

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have multiple `Route::group` in my route.php file, I am not able to access middleware inside another `Route::group`.

Here is an example code snippet

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //Login Routes...
    Route::get('/admin', 'AdminAuth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
    Route::get('/admin/login', 'AdminAuth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
    //Route::post('/admin/login', 'AdminAuth\AuthController@login');
    //Route::get('/admin/logout', 'AdminAuth\AuthController@logout');

    // Registration Routes...
    Route::get('admin/register', 'AdminAuth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
    Route::post('admin/register', 'AdminAuth\AuthController@register');

    Route::group([['middleware' => ['admin']], 'prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
        Route::get('/admin', array('uses' => 'AdminController@index'));
        Route::get('/departments', array('as' => '_departments', 'uses' => 'DepartmentController@index'));
        Route::get('/department/add', array('as' => '_department_add', 'uses' => 'DepartmentController@add'));
        Route::post('/department/add', array('as' => 'add', 'uses' => 'DepartmentController@add'));
    });
});
```

From above code  `Admin` middleware is not accessible, but If I place `Admin` middleware on top `Route::group` it works.

Now, I use  admin middleware inner `Route::group`, because outer route group does not require to check auth

Comment: I got solution of the above issue, problem was misplaced `prefix` key and value, it should be like `['middleware' => ['admin'], 'prefix' => 'admin']`